# sorting in javascript on condition or don't sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

i have an array of objects and i want to sort it only if there is an episode number otherwise i don't to sort it or do anything i want to keep the data as it is. Problem is using this code the sorting works well when i have episode numbers. the other case the data changed of order means the sort worked and i don't want this to happen. any help would be appreciated

```
     const episodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.episodes).sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.Number && b.Number) {
                return a.Number - b.Number
            }
        });
```

i have 2 cases Number exists like this array of objects that i want to sort and it's actually sorted well by Numbers no problem here:

```
    [
       {
        description: "Toda a atualidade."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: 321
        id: "PROGRAMID_14807272"
        },
        {
        description: "sobre as principais notícias do dia."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: 322
        id: "PROGRAMID_148057788"
        },
        {
        description: "notícias do dia."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: 320
        id: "PROGRAMID_148074755"
        }
    ]
```

or Numbers are null like this case where i wxant to keep it like this without sorting bit it's somehow sorted so the order is changing so the outcome i'm looking for is the same thing without any changes but what i'm getting is the order mixed:

```
    [
       {
        description: "Toda a atualidade."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: null
        id: "PROGRAMID_14807272"
        },
        {
        description: "sobre as principais notícias do dia."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: null
        id: "PROGRAMID_148057788"
        },
        {
        description: "notícias do dia."
        duration: 5400000
        Number: null
        id: "PROGRAMID_148074755"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: do you have some examples and wanted outcome?

Comment: this works? and what if the number `0` appear? it will be falsy even if its an number

Comment: i have 2 cases either the data coming from backend like a.Number and b.Number are all nulls or all of them are integers. if all the values are null i don't want to do the sort otherwise i want to sort the data so i want to ignore the sort inside the sort function

Comment: please add some data.

Comment: i added an example please check

Comment: do you have only all items with number or all items without?

Comment: 2 cases backend returns all the data with numbers or all the data with numbers values are null. first case okay but second one i got the order of the array of objects changing which is not what i want so the answer to your question is yes

Comment: @Ahmed-FadhelAchour. Do you want the objects to keep their indexes in the array when the Number is null and all the remaining are ordered on the indices occupied by Object with a Non null Number ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort by `Number` property.

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.Number - b.Number)
```

If the value is `null`, then `null` is converted to zero by using where a number is expected.. By returning zero for sorting the elements keeps the actual order.

```js
console.log(null - null);
```

Answer (score -2):

don't really understand your question.
just check if the condition is met then sort else break?

```
`if (episodesIsNumber()){
  sortArray();
}else{
  //doNothing
}`
```

Comment: check the example i've just added